# Mount VMDK with command line on Windows 10 based on VMWare Workstation

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmdk

We can use VMWare Workstation's GUI to mount a vmdk(with NTFS file system) on Windows, but after a lot of search, I still don't know how to do it with command line. It's better to be a command line tool from VMWare Workstation's install folder.

Environment:Windows 10 x64, VMWare Workstation Pro 15.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to boot a virtual hard disk on windows boot menu this can be solved with bcdboot here is a reference https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di
But bcdboot only works with vhd and vhdx formats.

If you only want to create a new VM based on your VMDK disk here is a tutorial
from vmware https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2010196

Good Luck !

Comment: Sorry that's not my need. I need to mount the disk and access the content in Windows 10 host.

Comment: You i'll need to map that virtual disk with the windows explorer options, but you need vmware workstation installed on your pc first here is a reference for your problem https://www.kjctech.net/mount-a-vmdk-image-file-in-windows/

Comment: I've downloaded this https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=VDDK670&productId=614 , which is version 6.7, but there is no vmware-mount.exe. Indeed the question is about why there are no vmware-mount.exe in the VMWare Workstation installation folder---how does VMWare mount disk?